# Is php://input written to a temp file for large uploads?

Tags: php, post

Is php://input written to a temp file for large uploads? I mean, is it safe to send 200 MB in the post body, assuming that all ini directives are set? I don't see any notes in the PHP docs about it, just that it is a stream. Maybe that is assumed (that it will go to a temp file if needed)?

The reason it could be needed is related to iOS video upload.

ex. [What is the correct way of sending large file through HTTP POST, without loading the whole file into ram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626748/what-is-the-correct-way-of-sending-large-file-through-http-post-without-loading)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106009/php-input-stream-size-limitations

Comment: It doesn't address the subject, but helpful.

Comment: Not PHP specific, but generally "network stream" (which is how HTTP requests would come in) is not "written" anywhere - one need to read from stream and do something with the data (including simply ignoring it) - i.e. as shown in answer suggested by @Dagon copying stream directly to file demonstrates that particular version of PHP did not buffer that stream in memory.